# Как отправить массив свойств в компонент?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Работаю с React. Имеется функция, который возвращает компонент:

```
export const createFormsElement = (name, component, additionalProps = []) => {
    return <Field name={name} component={component})}/>
}
```

`additionalProps` - это массив свойств, который выглядит примерно вот так:

```
[
    {placeholder: 'Введите пароль'},
    {type: 'password'}
]
```

То есть содержит объекты свойств, в которых содержатся пары ключ-значение. Мне надо каким-то образом разделить `additionalProps` на отдельные свойства и передать их в компоненту. Чтобы в итоге, когда свойства придут в функцию, получилось что-то вроде этого:

```
<Field name={name} component={component} placeholder={'Введите пароль'} type={'password'})}/>
```

Каким образом я могу это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавить их можно через `...`

```
const createFormsElement = (name, component, additionalProps = {}) => {
  return <Field name={name} component={component} {...additionalProps} />
}
```

Только `additionalProps` не массив объектов, а один объект

```
{
  placeholder: 'Введите пароль',
  type: 'password'
}
```